# Верно расставить знаки препинания

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте, подскажите, пжл, как лучше расставить знаки препинания в этом предложении:

Инженеры: Городков А.В., Смирнов К.Я., Петров М.Ю.; геологи: Иванова М.Д, Сванкова Р.Б.; полярники Катов П.Л и Столиков П.И., рабочий Калинин И.И. знали его и относились к нему с глубоким уважением.

Answer (score 1):

**Инженеры** Городков А.В., Смирнов К.Я., Петров М.Ю., **геологи** Иванова М.Д, Сванкова Р.Б.,  **полярники** Катов П.Л и Столиков П.И., **рабочий** Калинин И.И. знали его и относились к нему с глубоким уважением.

Приложения стоят перед рядом собственных имен.